Shift/translation functor of $R$-linear triangulated categories
Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $(\mathcal T,\Sigma)$ be an $R$-linear triangulated category. If $X \in \mathcal T$ is such that $r\cdot id_X=0$, then must it be true that $r\cdot id_{\Sigma X}=0=r\cdot id_{\Sigma^{-1} X}$ ?
I know this is true, for instance, like the derived category of $R$-modules, but what about in general?

For sure you should assume that $\Sigma$ is an $R$-linear functor when talking about an $R$-linear triangulated category. (It is unnatural to define this notion only by referring to the underlying category.) And then it's trivial. Please clarify your definition.

@MartinBrandenburg: I guess that was one point I was confused about ... is it standard to assume the shift functor is $R$-linear when talking about $R$-linear triangulated categories?

I already answered this. But it's your turn. Which definition do you use? What is the context? Are you working with a paper or book? Which one?
